# How to check whether .dll is loading again?

Tags: jsp, java-native-interface

i used .dll in JSP.

In a first Jsp program i did a code to forward   another JSP page.

which again uses the same dll

So my question is does that forwarded page again loads the

library?

Or it loaded once?

i code System.loadlibrary("lib") in a separate class

and created a object for that class in first JSP page and also in the forwarded JSP page.

Suppose if it is loading again ! how to make the .dll should be loaded once?

I am using apache tomcat web server 6.0.20.

Thanks in advance

krishna

Comment: You know that you don't have to add line breaks at the right side of the editor window? Because, you know, it will automatically wrap words anyway...

Answer (score 0):

`System.loadLibrary()` uses `Runtime.loadLibrary()`; the [documentation for that function](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> If this method is called more than once with the same library name, the second and subsequent calls are ignored.

So as long as your library is only installed as one name, you won't have this problem.